# Where does the expression $eV$ in Stopping potential come from?

Tags: classical-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

I was reading up on the photoelectric effect and I couldn't help but wonder, Where does the expression $(1/2) mv^2 = eV$ where $V$ is the stopping potential come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring a charged particle of mass $m$ and charge $q$ moving at a speed $v$ to a stop, something must do an amount of work
$$W = \Delta K = K_f - K_i = 0 - \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = - \frac{1}{2}mv^2\,.$$If the "thing" doing work is the electric field, we can instead recast the work done as a change in potential energy: the change in kinetic energy is equal to minus the change in electric potential energy, which is given by $q\Delta V$, where $\Delta V = V_f - V_i$ is the electric potential difference between the initial and final points. So, in other words,
$$
\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = e\Delta V\,,
$$
and the $\Delta V$ is therefore known as the *stopping potential*.